# How to download text file and read it using a phonegap for android

Tags: android, cordova

Hi how do we download text files using phonegap framework .can we use javascript or do we phone gap apis for it? I tried to look into phone gap documentation but couldn't find anything regarding downloading of files.Please help.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to use the File API, specifically the FileTransfer object: http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.5.0/phonegap_file_file.md.html#FileTransfer